# How to update item by primary key and other conditions?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update item by `email` (HASH PK), `id` and `verifyToken`. My query looks like this:

```
params =
  TableName: 'users'
  Key:
    email:
      S: 'example@email.com'
  AttributeUpdates:
    verified:
      Action: 'PUT'
      Value:
        BOOL: true
    verifyToken:
      Action: 'DELETE'
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
    ':id': { S: '123' }
    ':verifyToken': { S: 'XXX' }
  ConditionExpression: 'id = :id and verifyToken = :verifyToken'

dynamodb.updateItem(params)
```

In other words I want to update Item where email = 'example@email.com' AND id = '123' AND verifyToken = 'XXX', but I am getting following error:

```
Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: 
Non-expression parameters: {AttributeUpdates} 
Expression parameters: {ConditionExpression}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are combining legacy parameters (`AttributeUpdates`), which are only there for backwards compatibility, with expression parameters (`ConditionExpression`). As the error states, you cannot do that.

You need to use an [`UpdateExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression) in conjunction with your `ConditionExpression`.

It would be something like this. You may need to use expression attribute names/values in the `UpdateExpression`:

```
ConditionExpression: 'id = :id and verifyToken = :verifyToken'
UpdateExpression: 'SET verified = true, REMOVE verifyToken'
```

See [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html) for more information on update expressions